# Google Calendar API: Same Day Reminder for All-Day Event?

Tags: google-calendar-api

I'm using Google Calendar API v3 to create an all-day event with a reminder.  The [Event resource](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events) has a "reminders" property, but you can only specify the number of minutes since the start of the event.  It seems, the latest you can set a reminder using the API is midnight the night before the all-day event.

When using the google calendar's web interface you can specify a reminder to happen anytime on the same day as the all-day event.  (Enter "0 days" before, and enter any time you want.)

Does anyone know if you can somehow set a reminder to happen on the same day as an all-day event when using the API?

Answer (score 0):

As far as the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/reference/events#reminders.overrides) shows and as you have also mentioned, the latest supported property available is `reminders.overrides[].minutes` which can be set to a number of minutes before the start of the event when the reminder should trigger. Valid values are between 0 and 40320 (4 weeks in minutes).

In [Overriding default reminders](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/concepts/reminders#overriding_default_reminders), set `reminders.useDefault` to `false` and populate `reminders.overrides` with the new reminder set.

```
"reminders": {
  "useDefault": "useDefault",
  # Overrides can be set if and only if useDefault is false.
  "overrides": [
      {
        "method": "reminderMethod",
        "minutes": "reminderMinutes"
      },
      # ...
  ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but that doesn't allow me to set a reminder on the same day as the all day event.  The latest you can set a reminder with this method is midnight the night before the all day event.  I'd like for example to set an alarm for 9am on the day of the all day event.

Comment: I don't think it's possible. You may check this [forum](https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/calendar/tPeNA-NEqPI) and vote for it too.

Comment: Thanks, I think you're right that it isn't currently possible.  I've made a feature request here:  https://code.google.com/a/google.com/p/apps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4864  If anyone else wants this too, please star it.